# Can I create another context to send through sum values

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to create another context to send another query set through to the HTML. I want to send the sum of all total sales from the Transaction model to the HTML. Is this possible and if so how would I go about it?

View Below

```
@login_required
def portfolio(request):
    context = {
        'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').annotate(
            sum_amount_purchased=Sum('amount'),
            sum_total_price_purchased=Sum('total_price'),
            sum_amount_sold=Sum('sales__amount_sold'),
            sum_amount_current=F("sum_amount_purchased") - F("sum_amount_sold"),
            avg_amount_per_coin=Avg("amount_per_coin"),
            sum_total_price_current=ExpressionWrapper(F("sum_amount_current")*F("avg_amount_per_coin"),
                                                      output_field=DecimalField()),
            sum_total_income=Sum('sales__total_price_sold'),
            sum_profit_loss=F("sum_total_price_current") + F("sum_total_income") - F("sum_total_price_purchased"),
        ),
        'totals': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).annotate(
            total_spends=Sum('total_price'))
    }
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

HTML below

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
      {% for total in totals %}
    <h1> Total Spent: {{ total.total_spends }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Transaction model below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+self.currency + ', '+str(self.amount)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('transaction-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Sale model below

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sales")
    amount_per_coin_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+','+str(self.amount_sold) + ', '+self.note

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin_sold = self.total_price_sold / self.amount_sold
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sale-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in "multiple contexts":

```
context = {
        'transactions': ...
        'totals': ...
        'title': ...
}
```

access these values in the template with no additional prefixes, like:

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
      {% for total in totals %}
      <h1> Total Spent: {{ total.total_spends }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Note, to get "total sum" you need to switch from annotation to an [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet):

```
Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).aggregate(total_value=Sum('total_price'))
```

the output will be like `{total_value: 123}` so there is no need for a loop anymore. So you can access it in the template like `totals.total_value` (or even pass it as a scalar value from the view).

Comment: Hi @Ivan When i try it like that it returns 8 results for me when all i want is 1 sum result of the total column, any ideas what is going wrong? I will edited the view and HTML section in this post with my new code my new code

Comment: Try `aggregate` instead of `annotate` for `totals`

Comment: When i aggregate I dont get any results in my HTML

Comment: Because there is no list/loop anymore.

Comment: Did you finally make it? Was this answer helpful?